# Responsibility of Controller or Service?

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a question about responsibility of Controller and service about a piece of my code. I have a HTML form to save an article which can submit three image(thumbnail, summary and body) with their text. The body text can contains some images in Base64 format. I get them by a post Action which accept a DTO object to support all inputs.

The Tasks I want to do are:

1. Get DTO from client
2. Fetch images from body
3. Check Summary and body text rules
4. Check Fetched images rules
5. Check Thumbnail, summary and body image rules
6. Save them

I have a service layer here which has some class about checking article texts and images logics.

My question is that how should I act here. Which steps are for Controller and which ones for Service.

Step 2 is most confusing step to me. Should I do it in controller or just pass all DTO to Service to separate things itself?

Or about checking text, should I check for example summary text length in controller or it should be check by Service layer?

Can any one explain these to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080532/what-is-the-job-of-controller-in-mvc).

The responsibility of the controller, is to accept a request, invoke the processing, and respond according to the result of the processing.
Try to look at the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles and always try to apply them.

So first of all, DTO, it depends on your architectural design, but I would say that the DTO is the abstraction that allows you to decouple you Domain Model from the client model.
The DTO should be seen as the data representation between two layers, if the DTO crosses more than one layer, it probably isn't a DTO but a business or data entity.

> ) Fetch images from body

this looks like something you designed to be able to receive the desired data, but is not something your domain model cares about.
For example if your form allow you to save "Sale advert", which is made of few images and some text, probably this aggregation of data in your business layer (service), is represented by one or more domain objects, so the fact that you receive a body in whichever format, depends more on technology or transport, and should be transparent to your business layer.
A good example to help you find boundaries, is thinking about re-usability. How would you reuse your service layer if you were to use it from a WCF service for example?
Your service should always receive and expose Domain Objects.
Leave to the consumer component the responsibility to decode/encode.

> 3) Check Summary and body text rules (and all other checks)

seems to be a validation, but I cannot tell if this validation is only related to the domain.
Some validation is also done in the controller itself to check if the request is valid or not. 
So if this check is done on the DTO structure, before you try to convert it, probably that is a controller validation, if instead, this validation is necessary to decide weather or not the input can be saved, well probably in this case it would be considered other's responsibility.
You mentioned:

> for example summary text length

if this is a business rule, then I would place it in a validation object, responsible to validate the "summary text" or let's call it again "Sale advert".

The responsibility to save a domain object to a data store, is normally delegated to a Data Access Layer, which is coupled to the database structure and provides the abstraction to the business layer.
This can be done implementing a repository pattern or maybe using an ORM, I normally don't add logic to persist data in the business layer.

Another note, here you are asking about controller responsibility, but pay attention to your service "layer", I have seen often code where a huge service class, was encapsulating all the business logic and validation, that is very bad because again goes against most of the solid principles.
Look at the command query and decorator pattern, I love them because the really help you breaking down your code in smaller pieces with single responsibility.
If interest look at this example project on [github](https://github.com/norcino/net-core-cqrs-api) (.net core).
I am still working on the documentation but should be clear enough.